# String comparison with in the table

Tags: sql-server-2008, substring

I have two columns with similar data (shown below)

**Table1**

```
CHMedicalCorpINC  
UniversalStd  
SummitCorp
```

**Table2**

```
CHMedicalCorp  
UniversalStdOrlando  
SummitCorpINC
```

I want to compare the two columns letter by letter; if I am using substring then it displays values which match up 13 letters or those which have perfect match.

So the output gives me only the `CHMedicalCorp` not the other two columns. And I want the other two columns to be displayed

```
SUBSTRING(a.table1, 1, 13) = SUBSTRING(c.table2, 1, 13)
```

I want it to show me anything that matched up to 13 or less. Is there a way to do that or a function which allows me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The query below will work if it has any Id in the table.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TableName T1
JOIN TableName T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
WHERE T1.Table1 like '%' + T2.Table2 + '%'
   OR T2.Table2 like '%' + T1.Table1 + '%';
```

If there is no Id in the table, you can use this way:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TableName T1, TableName T2 
WHERE T1.Table1 like '%' + T2.Table2 + '%'
   OR T2.Table2 like '%' + T1.Table1 + '%'
```

Sample execution with given data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Id INT, Table1 VARCHAR (100), Table2 VARCHAR (100));
INSERT INTO @TestTable (Id, Table1, Table2) VALUES 
(1, 'CHMedicalCorpINC', 'CHMedicalCorp'),
(2, 'UniversalStd', 'UniversalStdOrlando'),
(3, 'SummitCorp', 'SummitCorpINC'),
(4, 'Hello', 'Welcome');

SELECT T1.*
FROM @TestTable T1
JOIN @TestTable T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
WHERE T1.Table1 like '%' + T2.Table2 + '%'
   OR T2.Table2 like '%' + T1.Table1 + '%'
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it? as this is taking too long to be executed.